# Refresh the listview in fragment android

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have a  listview in left side fragment and dynamic fragment in right side.If a change is updates in right side view.I want to refresh the list view left side fragment.How to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: i have a listview that contains name and count in fragment A.i have another listview in fragment B.if the number of items in fragments B is increased then the count in left side fragment A should also be increased.For that purpose i need to reload the listview in fragment a.

Comment: I asked you post your code not for explanation. Description is not enough to provide solution

Comment: did you check adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

Comment: @praveenSharma I have tried i need to call it from fragment B.So there is no use of notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @GrIsHu I can't able to post my code.Just give a solution on understanding my description.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the fragment OnCreate looks like this:

```
private MySQLiteHelper      databaseHelper;
private Cursor              c;
private myCursorAdapter     cursorDataAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {

                ViewContext = rootView.getContext();

                databaseHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(ViewContext);
                c = databaseHelper.myquery();
...
}
```

To update the listview I call from a different fragment, an update function defined inside the fragment containing the listview:

```
public void updatelistview()
{
    Cursor c = databaseHelper.myquery();
    connettiDataAdapter.changeCursor(c);
    connettiDataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help you :-

```
ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTheList);
((BaseAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```